# XPath for extracting Data from Similar named Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML something like this:

```
<root>
   <A>
    <B>
      <Parameter_Name label="type_A">Text</Parameter_Name>
      <Parameter>ABC</Parameter>
    </B>

    <B>
      <Parameter_Name label="type_B">Number</Parameter_Name>
      <Parameter>123</Parameter>
    </B>

    <B>
      <Parameter_Name label="type_C">Date</Parameter_Name>
      <Parameter>YYYYMMDD</Parameter>
    </B>
   </A>
</root>
```

Notice the `<B> </B>` element repeats itself. How does the XPath look like if I have to access the value of `<Parameter>` for the Parameter_Name label "type_B" (which will be `123`). I am not looking for the hard coded approach of using `.../B[2]/Parameter`, I am trying to find out the generic XPath for that.

Hope the question was clear. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **[predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates)**:

```
/root/A/B[Parameter_Name/@label='type_B']/Parameter
```